# How to send user data captured in the view to C# class for calculations and then return the data back to view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I cannot figure out how to make my application work without putting all of my calculations in my controller. Best practice says that my calculation should be separate from the controller, but I am unable to import the model I use for my data in my C# class I use for calculations. I tried making a class that is the same as my data model in my C# calculation class but it cannot convert between the two models.

Right now I am able to capture user data and send it to my controller. When I try to send it from the controller to a c# class it won't work because the model is not compatible with my c# class. Can anyone suggest how to handle this, or give an example that handles this problem? I have written below an outline of how I have set up my program.

Model class:

```
preCalculationModel 
{
    data { get; set; }
}
```

Controller method:

```
ReturnCalculationsView(preCalculationModel model) 
{
    // sending user data to C# class I want to get back a 
    // model or something I can serve to my view
    resultsModel = calculation(model);

    return ("ReturnCalculationsView", resultsModel )
}
```

`Calculation.cs`:

```
calculationModel 
{
    data { get; set; }
}

public void calculation(model) 
{
    calculationModel.data = model.data;

    // do some calculations on data

    return model;
}
```

I have tried importing the model into my C# class, I have tried making a similar model to mock my `preCalculation` model in my C# class but these all called errors. This is what confuses me about ASP.NET MVC, how are we supposed to do operations on data outside of the controller?

Answer (score 1):

Move your calculation to a service class. For example:

```
public interface ICalculator
{
    CalculationResult DoCalculation (CalculationInput input);
}

public class Calculator : ICalculator
{
    public CalculationResult DoCalculation (PreCalculationModel  precalculationModel) 
    {
        // Perform calculations based on precalculationModel argument...
        return new CalculationResult(/*results of calculation*/);
    }
}
```

Set up your dependency injection so that this service can be injected into your controllers.

```
serviceProvider.AddTransient<ICalculator, Calculator>();
```

Then use your controller to translate/map between the view/dto models and the service models.

```
public class MyController
{
    ICalculator calculator;
    public MyController(ICalculator calculator)
    {
        this.calculator = calculator;
    }
    public ActionResult ReturnCalculationsView(preCalculationModel model ) 
    {
        var calculationInput = new CalculationInput(/* pass data from model */);
        var result = this.calculator.Calculate(calculationInput);
        var viewModel = new CalculationModel(/* pass data from result */);
        return View("ReturnCalculationsView", viewModel);
    }
}
```